# Do not work the AND condition in HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working with rails and I have two tables Post and Tags with habtm relation.

The followings sentences work:

```
@posts = Post.find(:all, :include=>:tags, :conditions => ['tags.term LIKE ? OR tags.term LIKE ?', "%Barcelona%", "%restaurante%" ])
```

or

```
@posts = Post.find(:all, :include=>:tags, :conditions => ['tags.term  in (?)', ['Barcelona','restaurante'] ])
```

But this one, with `AND` condition,  do not work:

```
@posts = Post.find(:all, :include=>:tags, :conditions => ['tags.term LIKE ? AND tags.term LIKE ?', "%Barcelona%", "%restaurante%" ])
```

I would like to know the sentence to obtain all the posts that contain both `tags.term`: "Barcelona and restaurante"

thanks in advance

Emilio

Comment: What do you mean by do not work? Does it give any error? are you sure there are rows which qualify those conditions?

Comment: Firstly, habtm and find with conditions are deprecated methods and you should not use them.
Try rewrite HABTM to explicit has_many and has_many through:
Your query is somehow invalid. Please post Rails error output.

Comment: Means that don't return any value and there some row that contain both tags. Don't return any error.

Answer (score 0):

I respond my self, works for me and hope can help somebody:

@posts = Post.find_by_sql("select * from posts p where (select count(distinct t.id) from posts_tags pt left join tags t on pt.tag_id=t.id  where t.term in ('Barcelona', 'restaurante')  and pt.post_id = p.id) >= 2")